# Bootstrap: opacity not working for <div>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap panel in which I am setting the opacity, but it is not working.
Background image is all set good. But a panel in the side needs to be transparent... rather translucent (50%). Its not happening. I have tried the `opacity`.
Below is the code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary halfOpacity">
        <div class="panel-body">
    <!--    <div class="card border-primary mb-3">
                <div class="card-block special-card"> -->
                    <p>
                        <div class="image" style="text-align:center;">
                            <img src="dise-resized.png" alt="DISE"> 
                        </div>
                    </p>
                    <p><br></p>
                    <p>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon info">Username:</span>
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter NTID" required>
                        </div>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon info">Password:</span>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" required>
                        </div>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
                    </p>
                <!--</div>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like:

```
div.halfOpacity {
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Below is the screenshot what it looks like now.
I need the white background to be translucent.
[image]

Comment: the code you provided is working fine, i think there is an issue with css path

Comment: you got that right. my css path was incorrect. but now a new problem.. along with the panel the username and password fields are also becoming translucent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!important` sometimes some classes cuz this problem or try `backgroud-color:transparent`

```
div.halfOpacity {
    opacity: 0.6 !important;
    // or background-color:transparent;

}
```